# jQuery get real margin if assigned by 2 classes

Tags: jquery, margin

I have the following issue:

I have some inline-block elements and I want to get the margin of the elements.
At the moment I do it like `this methods.settings.items.first().css('marginLeft')` which works like a charm, BUT I have assigned the margin using the class `.card` however on the tablet view I have `.tablet .card{ margin: 5px; }` which works fine and the browser inspector shows `margin: 5px` jQuery however still shows `margin: 10px`.

Any idea how to fix that?

Edit

> Okay, problem solved: I left an unneeded css animation on the items which animated the margin, this of course caused the jquery to pickup the value before it was done animating.

Comment: I think you'll have to show the relevant HTML and CSS for us to understand what you're really asking.

Comment: jQuery should always give you the elements style that is applied at the time, so are your elements actually displaying a margin of 5px when jQuery returns 10px? I made a quick [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vFVNF/) showing how jQuery returns the 'real' margin

Comment: Yes, they are showing the right, 5px margin. Will add the code.

Comment: Okay, so turns out I am trying to get the values to fast. Getting the values using the console works correctly. But is there anyway I can get the margin immediately when it is set? How do I know it is correct now?